# Slideshow with auto play and the ability to select via dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a slideshow, which works perfectly fine on its own, without the auto play function I've added to it. But as soon as I add the auto play function its loading pictures in below it and changing the look of my page.

The idea is to have five images in a slideshow which will automatically scroll, but if the user wants to select one of the particular images, they can do via the dots on the bottom.

I feel like I'm missing something quiet obvious, anyone got any ideas?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

window.plusSlides = function(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
};

window.currentSlide = function(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
};

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
$(".slideshow-container > .mySlides:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.slideshow-container > .mySlides:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.slideshow-container');
}, 3000);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 130em;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  img {
    @include curvededges();
    width: 130em;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    max-height: 85em;
  }
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev,
.next {
  display: none;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: none;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid $white 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: $white;
}

.dot_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 89em;
  left: 52em;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
    <div class="text">Providing a safe home for animals since 1988</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
    <div class="text">Providing a safe home for animals since 1988</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533738699159-d0c68059bb61?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0bb9888db1d270eab08c77f41120dfca&w=1000&q=80" />
    <div class="text">Providing a safe home for animals since 1988</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Gatto_europeo4.jpg/250px-Gatto_europeo4.jpg" />
    <div class="text">Providing a safe home for animals since 1988</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg" />
    <div class="text">Providing a safe home for animals since 1988</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>


<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div class="dot_box">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `carousal`

owl `carousal`

downlaod the carousal then add these css files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

html format

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

add these js files

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

now call the carousal

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

now you are done. follow the documentation for more options

Comment: I'm using a slideshow as the carousel I used before wouldn't work within a flex-box.